# Biometric Authentication navigating from main activity on back press it keeps promoting the biometric auth

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-activity

I am very new to android development. I need help when user back press from another activity to main activity the biometric is called I want to execute it only one time when the app start

```
  if (biomatricAvaliable()) {
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
```

the above code is in main activity it is called every time when user goes to main Activity.

Comment: Share some code of main activity and flow where to where

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is decide when you want to authenticate.  Do you want to auth only when the app starts (remember that if the app is briefly backgrounded on Android it can be restarted in the background, so this may happen more frequently than you like)?  Every X minutes?  Every X minutes after they last use the app?  These all change the scenario.  I'm going to assume you don't want them to authenticate once and be done with it forever, that's kind of pointless.

Once you've decided that, you need to test for that condition and add it to your if statement there.  For example, if you want it every few minutes, you'd write the last time they authenticated to shared preferences, check that shared preference here, and run authentication if it doesn't exist or if it was more than X minutes ago.  With a refresh would be similar with shared preference, but you'd update the time in onPause or whenever they do something important in the app.  But the main thing is deciding what should and shouldn't trigger authentication first.

Comment: I want to be it authenticated until the user kills the app

Comment: @Dkathayat1 That's probably a bad choice from a security point of view-  if you're going so far as biometric authentication, you don't want someone to be able to pick up the phone later and get in.  But if you want to do that, you'd store the fact he was authenticated in a global variable once he authenticates, and check that variable in the if